# Why does <br> tag add extra whitespace between lines, and how to eliminate

Tags: html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have an HTML snippet

```
<p>
 REMIT TO ADDRESS: <br></br>
 1233 Main St<br></br>
 Lockbox 123<br></br>
 Anytown USA<br></br>
<p />
```

which renders appropriately below when viewed in a browser as part of an HTML file.

REMIT TO ADDRESS: 
 1233 Main St
 Lockbox 123
 Anytown USA

When this same exact snippet is included in an HTML email message, in the same exact browser, or Outlook or it seems any other program, it ends up looking like

REMIT TO ADDRESS: 
 1233 Main St
 Lockbox 123
 Anytown USA

When I look at the source, in MS Edge, it looks like

REMIT TO ADDRESS: \u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e 
1233 Main St \u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e 
Lockbox 123 \u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e 
Anytown USA \u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003cbr\u003e

When I look at the source in Chrome, there's an extra 
 added after each line.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: `br` are void elements. So HTML requires `<br />` or `<br>`. But `<br></br>` becomes `<br /></br />`. However,  in XHTML `<br></br>` is the same as `<br />`.

Comment: A good tip would be to use a html validator, like https://validator.w3.org/, sharing the whole page ideally. These wont always flag all issues like this br double up, but they usually do.

Comment: It's worth noting that Firefox (for some bizarre reason) [interprets  `<br>` or `<br />` as `<br></br>`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6FYAF.png). This is not normal, and I'm not sure why they do this (at least in HTML5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `<br/>` or `<br>` is sufficient.
`<br>` works in HTML. In XHTML, the tag must end with /, so `<br/>`
`<br></br>` is not valid HTML, I guess that's why you see double-line in your source code
See here [W3school br tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Comment: I have just tried your exact HTML snipset and on browser, it renders similar to the one you get in HTML email